# Ubuntu 20.04 on Rasberry Pi 3 B Rev 1.2 - No Wlan0

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I have this Rasberry Pi:

```
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a02082
Serial      : 00000000f7b091c7
Model       : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I am booting from a MicroSD card which I have tried on two different robots. On the first one, the wifi works fine and wlan0 is defined.

My problem is on the other Robot, which I think is pretty close to identical there is no wifi. It has a fully charged battery. I can reach it over a ethernet wired connection without any problems. Here is what the ip tool says:

```
$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b0:91:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.180/22 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 13559sec preferred_lft 13559sec
    inet6 fdb7:7ac:6f0f:1:ba27:ebff:feb0:91c7/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591815sec preferred_lft 604615sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb0:91c7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 100.64.81.29/32 scope global tailscale0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:6240:511d/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9de5:29e2:b34f:2900/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have looked at many many posts about this problem but none have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not definitive: It looks like a hardware problem with the Raspberry Pi. I swapped in a different one of the same model and it seems to work. I still don't know for sure whether there's something transient or a permanent problem. But I guess it does happen!